# MSBuild - how to force "AfterBuild" target when I do deployment?

Tags: msbuild, web-config, web-config-transform

I have the following setup: ASP.Net MVC .Net 4.0 solution with 5 projects in it, and several solution configurations (*Site1-Stage, Site1-Live, Site2-Stage*, etc). The reason for this is simple - we deploy same codebase to multiple servers with different config settings.

To manage these configurations, I use the approach described by Troy Hunt in his [You're deploying it wrong! TeamCity, Subversion & Web Deploy part 1: Config transforms](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html) article. In 2 words - I do NOT have *web.config* in my SVN repo, instead I have *Web.Base.Config*, *Web.Site1-Stage.Config*, etc and *XmlTransformation* task in project *AfterBuild* target. During the build, the required *web.config* is generated based on selected configuration:

```
 <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.Base.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config" StackTrace="true" />
  </Target>
```

**Here comes the problem:** when I'm execute MSBuild like this:

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /P:configuration=Site1-Stage /t:rebuild
```

all goes well, web.config is properly generated for the *Site1-Stage* configuration. However, if I run this command:

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /P:configuration=Site1-Stage /t:rebuild /P:DeployOnBuild=True
```

I get the following error:

> "MySolution.sln" (rebuild target) (1) -> "MySolution\MyWebProj.csproj"
>   (Rebuild target) (3) -> (PreTransformWebConfig target) ->   C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.5\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1399,5):
>   error : Copying file Web.config to
>   obj\Site1-Stage\TransformWebConfig\original\Web.config failed. Could
>   not find file 'Web.config'. [MySolution\MyWebProj.csproj]

I tried to explicitly add "AfterBuild" target into MSBuild command line:

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /P:configuration=Site1-Stage /t:rebuild,AfterBuild /P:DeployOnBuild=True
```

but it resulted in the same error.

**Why do I need this:** it's a very isolated example, and in reality I'm trying to setup automated publishing from TeamCity CI server. I think if I add new build step with "Visual Studio (sln)" runner BEFORE my current publishing step, that would work, it will first rebuild the project (and generate web.config) - and then publish. However, i have lots of publishing steps (around 20 now) and I would like to avoid that. My understanding is that "Publish" process does the build as part of it, so I would like to "reuse" that.

**Question is:** how should I modify my MSBuild command line to force config transformation to happen?

Thank you.

Comment: You `AfterBuild` target does not have any outputs. It seems that MSBuild skips this target thinking that it is up-to-date. Add outputs (`Web.Config` in your case) to your `AfterBuild` target outputs.

Comment: Maybe use "BeforeBuild"? BTW do you have web.config included in csproj? I believe most publish activities relies on items in project rather than in folder - though didn't check it. If not - you can include web.config in project, while still have excluded it from source control

Comment: @Lanorkin - that worked! Thanks a lot - please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: which one of these two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe use "BeforeBuild"?

BTW do you have web.config included in csproj? I believe most publish activities relies on items in project rather than in folder. You can include web.config in project, while still have excluded it from source control.

Comment: @avs099, do you need to include web.config into project or into source control? (even though it will be overwritten by the transform...)

Comment: @Mobigital i don't include it